# Nexus: Unknown Task called "Storage facet cleanup"

Tags: nexus

I installed Sonatype Nexus OSS 3.6.2-01
and although I did not configured any Scheduled Tasks I can see in the commandline that Nexus is running a task called "Storage facet cleanup" every ten minutes.

Because of I could not find anything about this task I finally came up here.

```
2017-12-20 08:40:00,013+0100 INFO  [quartz-3-thread-19]  *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.quartz.internal.task.QuartzTaskInfo - Task 'Storage facet cleanup' [repository.storage-facet-cleanup] state change WAITING -> RUNNING
2017-12-20 08:40:00,051+0100 INFO  [quartz-3-thread-19]  *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.quartz.internal.task.QuartzTaskInfo - Task 'Storage facet cleanup' [repository.storage-facet-cleanup] state change RUNNING -> WAITING (OK)
2017-12-20 08:50:00,014+0100 INFO  [quartz-3-thread-19]  *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.quartz.internal.task.QuartzTaskInfo - Task 'Storage facet cleanup' [repository.storage-facet-cleanup] state change WAITING -> RUNNING
2017-12-20 08:50:00,029+0100 INFO  [quartz-3-thread-19]  *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.quartz.internal.task.QuartzTaskInfo - Task 'Storage facet cleanup' [repository.storage-facet-cleanup] state change RUNNING -> WAITING (OK)
2017-12-20 09:00:00,015+0100 INFO  [quartz-3-thread-19]  *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.quartz.internal.task.QuartzTaskInfo - Task 'Storage facet cleanup' [repository.storage-facet-cleanup] state change WAITING -> RUNNING
2017-12-20 09:00:00,031+0100 INFO  [quartz-3-thread-19]  *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.quartz.internal.task.QuartzTaskInfo - Task 'Storage facet cleanup' [repository.storage-facet-cleanup] state change RUNNING -> WAITING (OK)
2017-12-20 09:10:00,016+0100 INFO  [quartz-3-thread-19]  *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.quartz.internal.task.QuartzTaskInfo - Task 'Storage facet cleanup' [repository.storage-facet-cleanup] state change WAITING -> RUNNING
2017-12-20 09:10:00,032+0100 INFO  [quartz-3-thread-19]  *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.quartz.internal.task.QuartzTaskInfo - Task 'Storage facet cleanup' [repository.storage-facet-cleanup] state change RUNNING -> WAITING (OK)
```

What is this task for?

Why is it not visible in the "Tasks" Section of the admin-panel?

Is there a way to disable this task (or configure it running only at night)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a cleanup task which is required to have NXRM run correctly.  It is not listed because it's not disablable/configurable.

Comment: Ugh, it runs like every day and really tends to bog down the system. Wish it was at least scheduleable.

Comment: This completely stops mine from working. The mirrors I have aren't accessible and I can't access the UI. How do I fix this?

Comment: @Micky-D suggest another question or posting on community.sonatype.com asking for help.  Troubleshooting your server via comments will not be possible.

Answer (score 0):

This is a cleanup task defined in the class [`StorageFacetCleanupTask`](https://github.com/sonatype/nexus-public/blob/f4316cbb68f776d4af2dafe1aca146c138783e50/components/nexus-repository/src/main/java/org/sonatype/nexus/repository/storage/internal/StorageFacetCleanupTask.java) which run `performDeletions()` on the `storageFacetManager`:

```
 @Override
  protected Void execute() throws Exception {
    thread = Thread.currentThread();
    long count;
    do {
      count = storageFacetManager.performDeletions();
    }
    while (count > 0 && !isCanceled());
    return null;
}
```

The method `performDeletions` is defined in [`StorageFacetManagerImpl`](https://github.com/sonatype/nexus-public/blob/f4316cbb68f776d4af2dafe1aca146c138783e50/components/nexus-repository/src/main/java/org/sonatype/nexus/repository/storage/internal/StorageFacetManagerImpl.java) and it delete all buckets marked with `P_PENDING_DELETION`:

```
    @Override
      @Guarded(by = STARTED)
      public long performDeletions() {
        List<Bucket> buckets = findBucketsForDeletion();
        return buckets.stream().filter((bucket) -> {
          try {
            log.info("Deleting bucket for repository {}", bucket.getRepositoryName());
            deleteBucket(bucket);
            return true;
          }
          catch (Exception e) {
            log.warn("Unable to delete bucket with repository name {}, will require manual cleanup",
                bucket.getRepositoryName(), e);
            return false;
          }
        }).count();
      }
```

All buckets marked with `P_PENDING_DELETION` are collected by `findBucketsForDeletion` in [`StorageFacetManagerImpl`](https://github.com/sonatype/nexus-public/blob/f4316cbb68f776d4af2dafe1aca146c138783e50/components/nexus-repository/src/main/java/org/sonatype/nexus/repository/storage/internal/StorageFacetManagerImpl.java):

```
private List<Bucket> findBucketsForDeletion() {
    return inTx(databaseInstanceProvider).call(db -> {
      return StreamSupport
          .stream(bucketEntityAdapter.browse(db).spliterator(), false)
          .filter((bucket) -> bucket.attributes().contains(P_PENDING_DELETION))
          .collect(Collectors.toList());
    });
}
```